# Conditional AS_ARG_WITH in configure

Tags: autoconf

I have some custom autoconf macros that will be shared by several projects. I would like to have some of the `AC_ARG_WITH` macros depend on the project, so they don't show up when they do `./configure -h`. For example:

```
if test $PKG_NAME = proj1; then
    AC_ARG_WITH(foodir, AC_HELP_STRING([--with-foodir=DIR],
        [where foo will come from]),
        foodir=$withval,
        foodir="")
fi
```

I've tried things like `m4_if` and `AS_IF` but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this, or am I SOL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So out of luck, I'd imagine. I was interested so tried coming up with a solution. I thought this might have been a possible `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([Autohell], [0.0.1])
AC_PREREQ(2.13)

AC_ARG_ENABLE([extras],[AC_HELP_STRING([--enable-extras],[Enable extra options])],
[
    AS_CASE([$enable_extras],
    [yes],
    [
        AC_ARG_ENABLE([foo],[AC_HELP_STRING([--enable-foo],[Enable the Foo])],
        [
            enable_foo=$enableval
            echo "Foo Enabled"
        ],
        [
            enable_foo="no"
            echo "Foo Disabled"
        ])
    ],
    [
        echo "Extras Disabled"
    ])
],enable_extras="no")

AM_CONDITIONAL([FOO],[test "$enable_foo" = "yes"])

cat << EOF

    Extras:  ${enable_extras}

        Foo: ${enable_foo}

EOF
```

Needless to say, it didn't work. Both `--enable-extras` and `--enable-foo` appear in `./configure --help` and the variables set by the switches are independent, check out this sample output:

```
$ ./configure

    Extras:  no

        Foo: 

$ ./configure --enable-extras
Foo Disabled

    Extras:  yes

        Foo: no

$ ./configure --enable-extras --enable-foo
Foo Enabled

    Extras:  yes

        Foo: yes

$ ./configure --disable-extras --enable-foo
Extras Disabled...

    Extras:  no

        Foo: yes
```

Output is quite interesting: although the switches and complementary variables are in place, the conditional blocks are respected so we can really only `--enable-foo` when we also `--enable-extras`.